# Firemonkey android how to set transparency form like widget and remove the black background system behind my app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a question about `firemonkey` inside android !

Is it possible to remove the black system background when my application launches ?

I mean: I want to make my main form application transparent and show just the Rectangle control like the widget in `dxscene` example ....
Finally, my problem is just how to remove the black background launcher which is a part of the android system and not a bug from `firemonkey`...

I think it just needs a few lines of API's code to resolve the problem...

Any way...if anyone want to reply, be sure that all your suggestions will be appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must play with

WindowManager.updateViewLayout(view, layoutparams); 
maybe something like FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

best is to decompile classes.dex and see the embarcadero java code of the activity

Answer (score -1):

ok i found the solution: is just by Modifying this line: (android:theme="%theme%") inside the <%uses-permission%> section from AndroidManifest.template.xml of your fmx project by this line: (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar") that all.
      nb: without parentheses. result here: https://youtu.be/dzEtNGTQjY8